# Como personalizar o tamanho de uma janela?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Como eu consigo personalizar o tamanho de uma janela que fiz usando a win32?

Meu Código:

```
 #include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
 MessageBox(NULL, "HELLO WORLD!","JANELA!", 0);
return 0;
}
```

Mas a janela ficou muito pequena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um `MessagaBox()` não pode ter seu tamanho determinado diretamente pelo programador. O tamanho é determinado indiretamente pela quantidade de texto colocado nele.

Se precisar determinar o tamanho mesmo, tem que usar uma janela normal com [`CreateWindow()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e pode criar uma personalização para se comportar com ose fosse um `MessageBox()`.

Cada um tem uma função específica na UI. Não faça a escolha por esse motivo. Pense se precisa de uma janela ou se precisa de uma caixa de mensagem simples e aceite a capacidade de cada um, isso foi pensado assim propositalmente.

Comment: OK... Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @Drkill32 dê uma olhada no [tour], a melhor forma de dizer obrigado é aceitar como fez e votar também. Você pode votar em tudo que foi postado no site (não só onde você participa diretamente.